# Finding the Length of a Pandas Dataframe Within a Function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The objective of the code below is to create another identical pandas dataframe, where all values are replaced with zero.

```
input numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#Given preexisting dataframe
len(df) #Returns 1502

def zeroCreator(data):
    zeroFrame = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(len(data),1))
    return zeroFrame
print(zeroCreator(df)) #Returns a TypeError: data type not understood
```

How do I work around this TypeError?

Edit: Thank you for all your clarifications, it appears that I hadn't entered the dataframe parameters correctly into np.zeros (missing a pair of parentheses), although a simpler solution does exist.

Comment: TypeError is being caused by passing `len(data)` and `1` into the the np.zeros function as separate args. The first arg should be the shape of your array as an "int or tuple of ints". The second arg if you choose to specify it, should be a data type like `numpy.float64`. You passed the int value of `1` into the second arg. If you intended this `1` to be the width of the returned DataFrame then you should combine `len(data)` and `1` into a tuple so it only uses one augment slot `np.zeros((len(data),1))`. Alternatively, if the width is to match the width of the source then `np.zeros(data.shape)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just clone a new df and assign `0` to it

```
zero_df = df.copy()
zero_df[:] = 0
```